# Wrong image content-type with Paperclip and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, content-type

I want to restrict my user's avatars. To do that, in my user model I've add `:s3_permissions` :

```
 has_attached_file :avatar,
                   :storage => :s3,
                   :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                   :s3_permissions => :private,
                   :path => "avatars/:id/:filename"
```

And, in my User controller:

```
def get_avatar
  redirect_to @user.avatar.expiring_url(10)
end
```

When users call to this method, through an API with a browser for example, they download the image instead show it.

I've noticed that the content-type of the image which I've download is:

```
content-type application/octet-stream
```

So I suppose that, maybe, it can be a reason that explain the facts.

How I could show the image instead download it?

Answer (score 0):

You should set content-type when you uploading the image by yourself. S3 does not guess/set content-type for you.